# Meaning of empathically in context of an advice or a warning

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empathically), *empathically* means *In an empathic manner*, [empathic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empathic) means *Showing or expressing empathy*, and [empathy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empathy) means *capacity to understand another person's point of view or the result of such understanding* (second meaning). I don't understand the meaning in the context of an advice, such as [in the wikivoyage article on Afghanistan](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Afghanistan):

> Travelling in Afghanistan is extremely dangerous, and independent travel/sightseeing is emphatically warned against.

Or, [another example](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kandahar):

> Kandahar remains extremely dangerous and is emphatically NOT safe for tourists.

How does this use of *empathically* relate to the definitions as I looked up in wiktionary? I fail to see how someone has a capacity to understand somebody elses point of view in this context. And how does the meaning of these sentences change if we remove the word *empathically*?

Comment: I think this question is Too Localised. I realise learners in particular may be more liable to miss that difference between **emphat...** and **empath...**. But ELL should not be concerned with such misreadings unless they're likely to affect a *lot* of people, which I don't think applies in this case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a false premise.


Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the wrong word. Do note my emphasis in those two examples:

Em**phat**ically, as in your quote, [has to do with](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/emphatically) *emphasis* - which is meant in your case: *emphatically warned against* means *strongly discouraged*.

And em**path**ically has to do with empathy, as your Wiktionary link suggests.